# Prevent NavigationBar from hiding with .searchable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm running into an issue with .searchable where I can't find a modifier or override to prevent the Search Bar from animating and hiding the Navigation Title and Tool Bar Elements when it's active.

Is this possible to prevent animating the `.searchable` text bar when active with SwiftUI?

Parent View

```
struct ParentSearchableView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var sessionStore: SessionStore
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@StateObject var groupViewModel: GroupViewModel
@State var searchString: String = ""
@State var privacy = 0
@State var alertString = ""
@State var selected: Bool = false
@State var showSelectedSheet: Bool = false
var isCreate: Bool

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        GroupInviteSearchContainerView(groupViewModel: groupViewModel, searchString: searchString)
        .searchable(text: $searchString,
                    placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always) )
        .onSubmit(of: .search) {
            // Do Someting
        }
    .navigationTitle("Invite Friends")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
    .navigationBarHidden(false)
    .background(Color.primaryDark)
    .toolbar() {
        Button("\(groupViewModel.listSelection.count) Selected") {
            showSelectedSheet = true
        }
    }
}
```

Search Container View

```
struct SearchContainerView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var sessionStore: SessionStore
@Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
@Environment(\.dismissSearch) var dismissSearch
@StateObject var groupViewModel: GroupViewModel
@State var searchString: String


var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if(groupViewModel.displayList.count > 0) {
            List{
                ForEach(groupViewModel.displayList) { user in
                    FriendSelectCellView()
                }
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .background(Color.primaryDark)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        } else {
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(false)
    .background(Color.darkBackground)
    .onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
        groupViewModel.isSearching = newValue
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you found how to solve the issue?